# How can I interpret this macro?

Tags: c++

I really wonder what the return value of soap_strcpy is?

```
# define soap_strcpy(buf, len, src) (void)((buf) && (size_t)(len) > 0 && (strncpy((buf), (src), (len) - 1), (buf)[(len) - 1] = '\0'))
```

My tool reports the return value is always false. 
The last condition below is a kind of usual expression? How can I interpret it?

```
(strncpy((buf), (src), (len) - 1), (buf)[(len) - 1] = '\0'))
```

Comment: @NGI Yes you do.  `operator&&` is an exception to the rule that parameter evaluation order is undefined.  `operator&&` is guaranteed to evaluate from left to right and to not evaluate the RHS if the LHS is false.  Consider that `if (ptr && *ptr == whatever)` is a very commonly used construct, and would not be valid if this were not true.

Comment: @Miles Budnek Thanks for correcting my wrong generalization of [Do not depend on the order of evaluation of subexpressions or the order in which side effects take place](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/EXP10-C.+Do+not+depend+on+the+order+of+evaluation+of+subexpressions+or+the+order+in+which+side+effects+take+place)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (strncpy((buf), (src), (len) - 1), (buf)[(len) - 1] = '\0'))

[Comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)? It's clearer now?

List of expressions, comma separated, the value of the expression is the one resulted by the evaluation of the last one in the list.

Since your last expression is an assignment  with zero, of course it will always be zero. This doesn't mean the evaluation of the whole list is useless: first term copies, last term terminates the copy with the zero char.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now, I think that my tool misinterpreted this macro's last condition is be assigned to zero.

Comment: @kongdol The value of an assignment is the assigned value. Try this `int foo() { int a; return a=1; }` and see the returned value. If you think of it, it makes sense; because 'int a=b=1;' needs to result in both `a` and `b` set to one, So the value of the assignment of `b` needs to be assigned to `a`.